# Angular 16 Standalone App and Component - Howto use selector in app.component.html

Tags: angular

I have created an Angular 16 App as Standalone and added Components with the --standalone flag.

Here are the Angular CLI Commands i have used:

```
ng new MyApp --standalone
ng g c footer --standalone
```

In app.component.html I want to use the footer selector (as known in Standard Angular Apps without the --standalone flag)

```
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

Angular 16 fires the following error:

'app-footer' is not a known element:

1. If 'app-footer' is an Angular component, then verify that it is included in the '@Component.imports' of this component.

What exactly dows this error mean? How can i solve this issue?

My general question:

Is it possible to link components as allready known with ngModules ?
Or is ist not possible to add standalone components to the main app.component.html with the selector tag?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It is mandatory to import the FooterComponent in the app.components.ts like the following example.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterOutlet,
    FooterComponent,
  ],
})
```

Answer (score 1):

In the component.ts file that you are trying to import the footer component into make sure that you have the footer component imported at the top:

```
    import{footerComponent} from '(your path to component')
```

for me this often looks like:

```
    import{footerComponent} from '../footer/footer.component'
```

then make sure you are importing it inside the @component declarator's imports array like this:

```
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-lesson-card',
      standalone: true,
      imports: [
      CommonModule,
      footerComponent,
      (any other components you want to use in this one),
       ],
```

It may also be worth mentioning that inside the above @component imports array you need the name of the component you are wanting to import exactly match the name of said components export class selector.

(inside the footer component):

```
    export class footerComponent {
    ////
    }
```

the above would give an error because the export has a lowercase "f" in footer but the component we are trying to import footer into is using a capitalized "F".